# How to prevent object to sort static fields alphabetically

Tags: python

I am using class with static values in python to represent some constants

```
class Constants(object):
    PERSON = "person_in_class"
    PARENT = "parent_of_person_in_class"
```

and lot of more, over 30 constants. I am using keys so I ma trying to make value short as possible ( on another side I have same file/class, and I am using haffman algorithm and it works), I generate pairs like

```
elements = [elem for elem in dir(Constants)if not startwith("_")]
```

but problem is that elements are always sorted alphabetically, so when I add new key in Constants I will change all, I want when I add at the end to be like have index.

Comment: Python objects store their attributes in a `dict`, and Python dictionaries do not preserve key order. Unfortunately, there's no way to enumerate class attributes in the order they were initially listed in their class definition.

Comment: You could hold a `collections.OrderedDict` in `Constants` and put your constants into that instead of using the class `__dict__`, but this will require some refactoring.

Comment: @jonrsharpe In that case, he doesn't need the class at all, does he? :)